# Export session variables easily and permanently in php

Tags: php, savegame

I feel like I must be missing something simple, or misunderstanding sessions or cookies. I want to save all session variables and allow players to copy/paste a long string to load the game up from a different computer or give to someone else, much like in Cookie Clicker or Adventure Capitalist etc. There is no need for sql, or for any kind of security; people can "cheat" if they want to.

Answer (score 1):

These things still usually work with SQL. Each saved game state gets a unique ID - usually a long string of hex characters - that identifies the entry in the DB. You then share this string.

You could do it without SQL using Mongo or the file system or something, of course.

Simpler games can get away with just encoding all of the game state into a string, but this will quickly become a *very huge string* (longer than is allowed in a cookie) for anything non-trivial. Old NES games would use this trick (using icons instead of letters for "passwords") but they had extremely little state to store (usually just which level you got to start at, and maybe a small set of upgrade items).